# Installing PySCIPOpt on Python 2.7 (Windows 10) via pip doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, scip

I just tried installing PySCIPOpt with pip by doing "pip install pyscipopt", however I get the following error message:

What am I doing wrong?

I'm running Python 2.7 on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine. It wouldn't let me post the question like this, so I deleted some obvious parts from the error message below.

```
Collecting pyscipopt
  Using cached PySCIPOpt-1.2.0.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyscipopt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyscipopt ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\daniel\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kejfxp\\pyscipopt\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmpaj_ydopip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  scipoptir:
  includedir: c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\include
  libdir: c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\lib
  running bdist_wheel
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyscipopt
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
  scip.c
  src\pyscipopt\scip.c(507) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'scip/scip.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyscipopt
  Running setup.py clean for pyscipopt
Failed to build pyscipopt
Installing collected packages: pyscipopt
  Running setup.py install for pyscipopt ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\daniel\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kejfxp\\pyscipopt\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-zqfl67-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    scipoptir:
    includedir: c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\include
    libdir: c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\lib
    running install
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyscipopt
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\include -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc\pyscipopt\scip.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\pyscipopt\scip.obj
    scip.c
    src\pyscipopt\scip.c(507) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'scip/scip.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\daniel\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-kejfxp\\pyscipopt\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-zqfl67-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-kejfxp\pyscipopt\
```

It still doesn't let me post the question, so here's some more text, maybe now it will work. It still doesn't. Maybe now?

Answer (score 2):

This question is already answered here: https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/issues/102

What was missing - apart from installing the SCIP Opt Suite - was to set the path to where the SCIP Opt Suite was installed:

```
set SCIPOPTDIR="C:\Program Files\SCIPOptSuite"
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

[Installation instructions](https://github.com/SCIP-Interfaces/PySCIPOpt/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) says:

> SCIPOPTDIR needs to have a subdirectory lib that contains the library.
>
> Additionally, if you're building PySCIPOpt from source, i.e. not using the precompiled egg or wheel, you also need to place all SCIP header files into a directory include next to lib (this is done automatically by make install INSTALLDIR=$SCIPOPTDIR SHARED=true of the SCIP Optimization Suite)

So first you need to install SCIP Optimization Suite.

Comment: Hmm I did that now, and I'm still getting the same error message. I simply downloaded an installer file for Windows, is that a "precompiled egg or wheel", or do I have to do some additional steps myself?